# Retrieve all data from the database got the second row same with the first row

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

This problem is not appear when I had combined both the models and the codes in the same class, but right now I already separate the models and the codes into different class. I made 2 column and each one have different value (data).

When I ran the program, it will retrieve all data from the database, and this is the result that I got: (Totally wrong)

**Database table (User) :**

[image]

However, when I check the database from the IDE (Visual Studio 2013), it appears correctly:

[image]

Here is the code that I am using:

**Model (UserContext) :**

```
public class UserContext
    {
        [Display(Name = "Username:")]
        public string Username
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

**Controller :**

```
UserManager manager = new UserManager();

public ActionResult List()
        {
            List<UserContext> user = manager.Fetch();

            return View(user);
        }
```

**Code Behind (UserManager) :**

```
public List<UserContext> Fetch()
        {
            List<UserContext> users = new List<UserContext>();

            UserContext context = new UserContext();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT [Username] FROM [User] ORDER BY [Username] ASC";

                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            context.Username = reader["Username"].ToString();

                            users.Add(context);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return users;
        }
```

**View (List View) :**

```
@model  List<Project_Name.Models.UserContext>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User List";
}

<h2>User List</h2>
<br />

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Username
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Label(item.Username)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is a problem was because I put the `UserManager` class outside the `Models` folder, and the `UserContext` inside the `Models` folder?

Thank you very much.

Your answer much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error occurs because you declare just one instance of `context`, and the  keep updating its `UserName` in the `while` loop (inside the while loop you just add another reference of it to the collection)

You need to declare a new instance inside the loop

```
while (reader.Read())
{
  UserContext context = new UserContext();
  context.Username = reader["Username"].ToString();
  users.Add(context);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Stephen Muecke, you da real MVP :D, you have answered and solved my question many times.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is in your UserManager. You need to create a new UserContext for each row you read from the database.

Move

```
UserContext context = new UserContext();
```

From where it is to inside the

```
while (reader.Read()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new instance in "each" while loop iteration like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
  UserContext context = new UserContext();
  .....
  .........;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no `WHERE` clause.  You're always going to end up with the last person selected.